# Anyone give word to word translation of Brahma sutra Shankara bhashya 1:3:38?

Tags: adi-shankaracharya, translation-request, brahma-sutras, translation

Anyone give word to word translation of Brahma sutra Shankara bhashya 1:3:38 ?

इतश्च न शूद्रस्याधिकारः यदस्य स्मृतेः श्रवणाध्ययनार्थप्रतिषेधो भवति। वेदश्रवणप्रतिषेधः वेदाध्ययनप्रतिषेधः तदर्थज्ञानानुष्ठानयोश्च प्रतिषेधः शूद्रस्य स्मर्यते। श्रवणप्रतिषेधस्तावत् अथ हास्य वेदमुपश्रृण्वतस्त्रपुजतुभ्यां श्रोत्रप्रतिपूरणम् इति पद्यु ह वा एतच्छमशानं यच्छूद्रस्तस्माच्छूद्रसमीपे नाध्येतव्यम् इति च। अत एवाध्ययनप्रतिषेधः यस्य हि समीपेऽपि नाध्येतव्यं भवति स कथमश्रुतमधीयीत। भवति च वेदोच्चारणे जिह्वाच्छेदः धारणे शरीरभेद इति। अत एव चार्थादर्थज्ञानानुष्ठानयोः प्रतिषेधो भवति न शूद्राय मतिं दद्यात् इति द्विजातीनामध्ययनमिज्या दानम् इति च। येषां पुनः पूर्वकृतसंस्कारवशाद्विदुरधर्मव्याधप्रभृतीनां ज्ञानोत्पत्तिः तेषां न शक्यते फलप्राप्तिः प्रतिषेद्धुम् ज्ञानस्यैकान्तिकफलत्वात्। श्रावयेच्चतुरोवर्णान् इति चेतिहासपुराणाधिगमे चातुर्वर्ण्यस्याधिकारस्मरणात्। वेदपूर्वकस्तु नास्त्यधिकारः शूद्राणामिति स्थितम्।।

Comment: This is a Bhashya, isn't it? Let us know the original mantra/ sukta first. A Bhashya itself is a word-to-word explanation (literally, for each word  is explained in individual capacity) so we should be able to differentiate between the word and it's explanation.

Comment: As I want word to word translation of bhashya in English

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this forum is not a translation website. There are many available translations available on the Brahma Sutras on the web.

Comment: Swami vishwanada you can show translation which as word by word translation. when you can talk about voting to close this